# Filepicker.io works in IE10, not in IE9 or IE8

Tags: filepicker.io

I have a problem with making filepicker.io work with IE versions other than the latest 10. Other browsers work fine.

[image]

I am attaching a simple code sample (the jQuery ready part is me trying to make it work). On IE8 and IE9, the "Pick File" button just does not show. A blank text input is shown instead.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20121008/json2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        filepicker.setKey('mykeygoeshere');
    });
</script>
<body>
    <input type="filepicker" />
    <script src="//api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js"></script>
</body>
```

At the same time, this https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#widgets-pick works.
What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to mention, that IE9 that we were testing on raised

*SCRIPT5009: 'JSON' is undefined*

and we had to add

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20121008/json2.js"></script>
```

to the code. Code above updated.

When we go to the debugger, it does not show any more errors. Moreover, the Network profiler shows, that filepicker initializes itself and pulls:

```
https://www.filepicker.io/dialog/comm_iframe/   GET 200 text/html   1,02 KB 171 ms  appendChild <frame>
```

Comment: I'm not positive that this will work, but try closing your input tag like
    <input type="filepicker" />

Comment: It does not change anything, unfortunately. I will debug more and add findings above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple, only the place to look for it required a little bit of an out-of-the-box approach.

We played with different compatibility modes, and it turned out, that IE chose this particular rendering mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" />
```

Not that the example file had any meta tags... but it started working, when content was set to  any of IE=8, IE=9 (not surprisingly), as in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx

Hope this will help someone. Case closed.