# Filepicker.io dialog not showing in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, filepicker.io

The title sums it up pretty much. This used to work in IE8 in the past, but it was reported in the last few days that IE8 users can't upload files, as a result of the Filepicker UI not being initialized at all.

Here's the error being displayed:
[image]

I also couldn't find any news from Filepicker.io if the problem is on their side, because there are no changes to that functionality on our side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991919/filepicker-io-works-in-ie10-not-in-ie9-or-ie8

have a peek at this post

Comment: @Kieranmv95 adding a `http-equiv` meta tag didn't help. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that was an issue of Filepicker itself. I contacted the support, they said a fix is included in the new release (25.08.2015). I can confirm it's all working well now.